# C# send VNC commands

Tags: c#, command, vnc

Is there any simple way in C# to send commands to a VNC server on a computer. Ideally some sort of library or something would be nice but whatever is simplest really. All I want to be able to do is just connect and send a command, I don't even want to view the desktop.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of command are you thinking of sending? A mouse button press? A keypress? A shell command?

Comment: Ah just keypresses. Such as CTRL-ALT-DELETE, general text etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [VncSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/).

Comment: That looks like it will work, but I don't see any option to send just text or a command like enter. I can only see the command SendSpecialKeys which only allows me to send things like control-alt-delete, any ideas?

Comment: @jack: I have no idea, it was the first result in duckduckgo.com.  I would try to send the 3 down keys before calling the key up event

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternative solutions
Method 1 :

```
Process pl = new Process();
pl.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
pl.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
pl.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
// = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; if you want to hide the window
pl.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

SendKeys.SendWait("11111");
```

Method 2 :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


// Get a handle to an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        // Activate an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        private void test()
        {
            IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame", "Calculator");

            // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
            if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
                return;
            }

            // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
            // a set of calculations.
            SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("111");
            SendKeys.SendWait("*");
            SendKeys.SendWait("11");
            SendKeys.SendWait("=");

        }
```